# How to append a text element with inline tspan children?

Tags: svg, d3.js

Starting with a DOM that already contains something like

```
<svg id="svg0" width="600" height="300" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">

</svg>
```

...I want to *programmatically* modify the element in `d3.select("#svg0")` so that I end up with

```
<svg id="svg0" width="600" height="300" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
<text x="20" y="20">
Lorem ipsum 
<tspan style="alignment-baseline:text-before-edge">dolor</tspan>
sit amet</text>
</svg>
```

This is as far as I can get:

```
var $svg = d3.select("#svg0");
$svg.append("text").text("Lorem ipsum ")
                   .attr({x:"20", y:"20"});
```

It looks as though the rest should be easy, but I've spent the last two hours trying all the "obvious" things to finish this without success.<sup>1</sup>

What does one have to do to finish the task described above?

<sub><sup>1</sup>I've tried far too many things to describe them all.  Suffice it to say that the `text` *method*, when used as a setter, wipes out whatever `textContent` the `text` *object* had before.  This means that, effectively, this method can be called only once, which precludes solutions relying on calling `.text(...)` a second time to add the " sit amet" fragment.)</sub>

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Normally you would think to use the `html` function for this, but from the docs:

> Note: as its name suggests, selection.html is only supported on HTML
>   elements. SVG elements and other non-HTML elements do not support the
>   innerHTML property, and thus are incompatible with selection.html.
>   Consider using [XMLSerializer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XMLSerializer) to convert a DOM subtree to text. See
>   also the [innersvg polyfill](https://code.google.com/p/innersvg/), which provides a shim to support the
>   innerHTML property on SVG elements.

Here's with the polyfill: http://jsfiddle.net/GNGF5/

And if you don't want to do that, you can hack it up using multiple `tspan` elements w/ a `transform`, as seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/cAuCM/

```
var $svg = d3.select("#svg0");
var $text = $svg.append("text");
var $tspan1 = $text.append('tspan');
var $tspan2 = $text.append('tspan');
var $tspan3 = $text.append('tspan');

$text.attr('transform', 'translate(0, 18)');
$tspan1.text('Lorem ipsum');
$tspan2.text('dolor').style('alignment-baseline', 'text-before-edge');
$tspan3.text('sit amet');
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's how to do it with [Snap.svg](http://snapsvg.io/):

```js
var paper = Snap("#svg0");
var t1 = paper.text(50, 50, "Snap");
var t2 = paper.text(50, 70, ["S","n","a","p"]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/snap.svg/0.1.0/snap.svg-min.js"></script>
<svg id="svg0" width="600" height="300" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
</svg>
```

Comment: The question mentioned use of d3.select, so Answer for Snap.svg doesn't look like what is asked for.